# Batch file to check version on mass computers

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file

Please help me to create a batch file to run the below command (multiple computers) and the result to a text file.

```
dtcheck "computername" /cmd="version"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it can do multiple PCs into one text file, but here is how the batch file code:

```
@echo off
dtcheck "computername" /cmd="version" >drive:\path\[name of the text file].txt
exit
```

Copy and paste it into notepad and save with .bat extensions, substitute the names and you should be all set to go.

If you need to have it run on multiple PCs, just change the name of the txt file to reflect a name of that PC and save them all to a network drive.

That would be my 2 cents.  Hope that helps.